# Why did Olivia's family celebrate Thanksgiving?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, this-is-us

In episode 8 of "This is Us", "Pilgrim Rick", Olivia opens up to Kevin and tells him:

> how Thanksgiving was always a difficult time for her growing up, with her father always leaving early to spend time with his mistress.

However, Olivia has a very strong English accent, which implies that she grew up in an environment where English accents were the norm - for example, England.

As Thanksgiving isn't a notable day in the UK, is there any in-universe explanation as to why her family were celebrating it?

Comment: Without ever having seen the show, is it possible that her family came from America to England and hence celebrated Thanksgiving in a british-accent region? Or maybe the other way around, her british family moved to the US, and she kept her accent from family interaction while celebrating a new holiday?

Comment: The former is entirely possible, with her then returning to the US as an adult. I'd be interested if this is addressed in the show or any surrounding materials though, as (being British myself) it struck me as very odd having her discussing it.

Answer (score 1):

Olivia's Mother is American, but she abhors Thanksgiving because she doesn't want to get together with "relatives she hates so they can gorge themselves on dry bird while pretending that they'd ever have anything to do with eachother if they weren't related by blood". Her plans, instead, are to go to a favorite dive bar.